# try-with-resources: Does Java make any guarantees about the order of calls to .close()?

Tags: java-7, try-with-resources

When using a try-with-resources in Java 7, are there any guarantees about the order in which `.close()` is called?

Here's some sample code from Oracle showing this feature:

```
try (
  java.util.zip.ZipFile zf = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(zipFileName);
  java.io.BufferedWriter writer = java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset)
) {

  // Enumerate each entry

  for (java.util.Enumeration entries = zf.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements();) {

    // Get the entry name and write it to the output file

    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String zipEntryName = ((java.util.zip.ZipEntry)entries.nextElement()).getName() + newLine;
    writer.write(zipEntryName, 0, zipEntryName.length());
  }
```

Both `zf.close()` and `writer.close()` will be called. Is the order guaranteed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [in the opposite order of declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), closing from the inside to the outside.